# Looking for a way to return documents from another collection based on a set from another, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

To start with, I have two collections, `users` and `sensors`. A user looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d471ec414197a868de1b533"),
    "email" : "example_email@hotmail.co.uk",
    "hashedPassword" : "hash",
    "confirmation_code" : "conf",
    "confirmed" : true,
    "sensors" : [
        "asde22re",
    ]
}
```

And a sensor looks like:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4c85d7b032b64f1c1a0b14"),
    "sensorId" : "asde22re",
    "data" : [
        {
            "data" : "10343",
            "time" : "2019-08-08T20:28:07.241Z"
        },
        {
            "data" : "11002",
            "time" : "2019-08-08T20:28:26.594Z"
        }
    ]
```

I have an endpoint `GET /sensors`, which is supposed to return data for all sensors of which a user has access too, this can be found in `users.sensors`.

I'm unsure how to actually google what I want (probably ignorance on my part), but essentially I need a query where given `users.email` it returns all the sensors that the respective user has access too.

One way I could do this is just by doing:

`dbo.collection('users').findOne({ email: 'example_email' })` and then using this response, get `users.sensors` and do a `foreach` on each sensor in the set, this seems inefficient though.

How can I combine that into one query?

Edit:
If it helps, this is what I am trying to replicate

```
dbo.collection('users').findOne({ email }, { fields: { sensors: 1, _id: 0 } }, (err, results) => {

    if(err){
        return res.json({ err });
    }

    const { sensors } = results;

    dbo.collection('sensors').find({ sensorId: { $in: [sensors] } }).toArray((err, results) => {

        if(err){
            return res.json({ err });
        }

        return res.json({ results });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to "joins" in sql, in Mongo you have to use "lookup".

To use lookup you have to use "aggregate" query,

So query that you need is,

```
db.collection('users').aggregate({$match:{ email: 'example_email' }},
    {$unwind:{path:"$sensors"}},
    {$lookup:{from:"sensor", localField: "sensors", foreignField:"sensorId", as:"sensorDetails"}},
(err, userData)=>{
      console.log(userData);
})
```

So what this query is doing,

see "$lookup" line ---> from "users" collection, it is using "sensors" field (local field to your user collection like the primary id in sql)  and fetch info from "sensor" collection matching to sensorId (foreign field in sensor collection),  and store the result in "sensorDetails" field.

you can have access to sensorDetails with "userData[0].sensorDetails".
sensorDetails will be array.

Check official docs about [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)
Also read about [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't quite get it working, so I changed it to this:
adbo.collection('users').aggregate({$match:{ email }}, { $lookup:{ from: 'sensor' , localField: 'sensors', foreignField: 'sensorId', as: 'sensorDetails' }}).toArray((err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
})`
Which just returns my user information. Does this have anything to do with the fact that the `sensors` field is an array?

Comment: Ya..    dbo.collection('users').aggregate({$match:{ email }}, { $lookup:{ from: 'sensor' , localField: 'sensors', foreignField: 'sensorId', as: 'sensorDetails' }}).toArray((err, res) => { console.log(err, res); })  this will work.

Comment: No.. this does not have anything to do with "sensors" field being array.

Comment: Ok, well this doesn't seem to return anything for me. All it returns is the actual user, without the sensor information. I also changed `from: 'sensors` to `from: 'sensors'`, and that didn't work either.

Comment: No, I missed the "unwind" pipeline.. there, try this now.  "from" field in "$lookup" indicates the second collection's name on which we are performing lookup not field name AND "foreignField" indicates a field from second collection which we have to use to for matching.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry. I'm not quite sure what you mean by you missed the unwind pipeline? This is what I've got: https://pastebin.com/eqBQrxtM, which isn't working. I'm not sure how to add the unwind pipeline

Comment: Hi, this didn't work either, also you need to change `from: sensor` to `from: sensors` as that is what the collection is called, and the field in users is also called sensors. Here is what I have tried, all it does it return what is at the bottom of the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/fueGmDUQ

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
dbo.collection('users').aggregate([{ $match: { email: 'example_email@hotmail.co.uk' } }, { $unwind: "$sensors" },
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "sensors",
        localField: "sensors",
        foreignField: "sensorId",
        as: "sensorDetails"
    }
}, {
    $group: { _id: '$_id', "userDetails": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }, "sensors": { "$push": "$sensors" }, "sensorDetails": { "$push": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$sensorDetails", 0] } } }
},
{ $addFields: { 'userDetails.sensors': '$sensors', 'userDetails.sensorDetails': '$sensorDetails' } },
{
    $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$userDetails" }

}])
```

With mongoDB v3.4 or above you can just use `$lookup` to achieve expected results, here you don't need to use `$unwind` on **localField** even if it's an array, it doesn't matter anymore :

```
dbo.collection('users').aggregate([{ $match: { email: 'example_email@hotmail.co.uk' } },
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "sensors",
        localField: "sensors",
        foreignField: "sensorId",
        as: "sensorDetails"
    }
}])
```