# How to Return the referenced entity in mongodb like mongoose does and not just the Id?

Tags: mongodb, one-to-many

In a one to many relationship in Mongodb, I want to get the whole that has the Id instead of just getting an Id.

I have searched in the Mongodb documentation and didn't find any answer for my situation.

My Books mongodb collection have the current fields,

```
{
 id,
 title,
 pages,
 price,
 authorId, //Id made with cuid
...
}
```

The Authors collection looks like this

```
{
id,
name,
...
}
```

I didn't have this problem When using a query with mongoose,As it does that for me automatically when I set the field in the Schema to

```
const bookSchema = new Schema({
...
authorId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'author'}
})
```

So,To have the same result using mongodb, Should I just make other queries to return the author with that Id in the authors collections or is there a simple way?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497393/filter-data-using-mongoose-populate/57617145#57617145 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430158/looking-for-a-way-to-return-documents-from-another-collection-based-on-a-set-fro/57432845#57432845

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need. I am going to flag my question as already asked!